# Use "with" twice in a sentence

Tags: repetition

Is it correct to use "with" twice in this phrase?

The ability of the people to acquaint themselves with and work together with ..."

Or should I say: "The ability of the people to acquaint themselves and work together with ..."

Comment: I'm not sure either construction is meaningful without more context, but the second is almost certainly less valid.  (There is no rule that a word can't be used twice in the same sentence.)

Answer (score 1):

The second suggests that two things are being discussed: the ability of people to get to know each other; and the ability of people to work with ... This is a strange mixture of ideas and does not read well.

The first suggests very clearly that two things are being discussed: the ability of people to get to know ... and the ability of people to work with ... These two ideas focus on the same object ("...") and make good sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit one *with*, make it clear that the remaining instance applies to both *abilities* by using commas:

> The ability of the people to acquaint themselves, and work together, with other people ...

In general, though, it's clearer to use both, because the second *ability* may get long-winded, and by the time you get to the *with* you've forgotten the first *ability*:

> The ability of the people to acquaint themselves, and work in a productive manner that adheres to company policy, together with other people ...